# Query to see if there are any documents that match

Tags: performance, solr, permissions, solr4

Is there a way to query Solr and find out if there are any documents that match a criteria?

I do not need or want the documents, and it would be ideal if I can do something like

(there was a document that matched AND ... ) as my query string

I ask as I am using some entity as a way to manage permissions, and this is seemed like it would work. Currently, my workaround is to have two queries, one that asks if there are documents that match a criteria, checks that at least one doc came back, and then sends the second one.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/select?q=YOUR_QUERY&rows=0
```

That will return something like:

```
{
-responseHeader: {
    status: 0
    QTime: 0
    -params: {
       ...
    }
 }
-response: {
    numFound: 383250
    start: 0
    docs: [ ]
 }
}
```

Then check if `response.numFound` is positive. The SQL equivalent of that would be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <table> WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: This is still searching for more than one though. I want it to stop after it found the first one (there is a lot of data, and a full search can take more than a few hundred milliseconds)

Comment: `numFound` is always returned. I don't know of any way to do what you want in Solr.